# How to open project properties for given project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension.

Given a particular project (an [`IVsHierarchy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.aspx) as returned by [VsShellUtilities.GetProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsshellutilities.getproject.aspx)), how can I open the 'project properties' window for that project?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to select that project in the Solution Explorer, get the EnvDTE.DTE instance and then call DTE.ExecuteCommand("Project.Properties")